# fl.transitions.Tween not found on ActionScript Mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, tween

I'm developing an ActionScript mobile project for Android.

When I add the following import, compiler says that is not found.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
```

How can I use Tween with mobile projects?

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;

    public class spriteButton extends Sprite
    {
        private var alphaOver:Tween;
        private var alphaLabelOver:Tween;
        private var alphaLabel:Tween;

        public function spriteButton(newLabel:String)
        {
            myLabel.text = newLabel;
            myLabelOver.text = newLabel;
            myLabelOver.alpha = 0;
            buttonMode = true;
            mouseChildren = false;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleMouseOut);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseUp);
        }
```

By the way, I'm very new on ActionScript 3.0 development.

I get this errors:

```
The import fl could not be found.
The import Tween could not be found.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1172: Definition fl.transitions:Tween could not be found.   spriteButton.as /Test01/src line 4  Flex Problem
```

Comment: Did use the import statement? "import fl.transitions.Tween;" If not post the full error message.

Comment: very odd import fl could not be found. I see it is in a custom class spriteButton. I am going out on a leap here but I bet you have something wrong in the first 10 lines of that class. Please post the first 10 lines of spriteButton.as

Comment: Question updated. I'm sure the problem is that fl.transitions.Tweens is not available on mobile projects.

Comment: From the error It can't locate the whole fl package

Comment: try this import fl.transitions.*; and import fl.transitions.easing.*

Comment: Also what IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 Standard.

Comment: according to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6 it is supported in AIR 1.0 so you should be able to get it.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with FB but check the project properties and see what libraries you are using. Also try and create a new mobile project and see if you can get the fl package from that.

Comment: @The_asMan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1940/discussion-between-vansfannel-and-the-asman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are new to AS3, then use this library: http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/ for tweenning objects.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question